# Storing Symbols like ϱπΩ÷√νƞµΔϒᵨλθ→%° in SQL Server XML

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2008

I ran these quires in my SQL server

```
select cast('<Answers>
  <AnswerDescription> ϱπΩ÷√νƞµΔϒᵨλθ→%° </AnswerDescription>
</Answers>' as xml)


select ' ϱπΩ÷√νƞµΔϒᵨλθ→%°'
```

And got the following results

```
   <Answers>
      <AnswerDescription> ?pO÷v??µ??????%° </AnswerDescription>
    </Answers>
```

and 
" ?pO÷v??µ??????%°"

How to make my SQL server store or display these values as they are being sent from Application ?

Comment: Are you sure everything involved is UTF-8 enabled? It could just be the application not able to print it.

Comment: The App is is UTF-8 I tested it , but as I stated above the SQL server is giving me those results. Is there a way I can change my SQL server to support these symbols.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In SQL Server, scalar string values are cast to `VARCHAR` by default.

Your example can be made to work by indicating that the strings should be treated as `NVARCHAR` by adding `N` before the opening single quote:

```
select cast(N'<Answers>
  <AnswerDescription> ϱπΩ÷√νƞµΔϒᵨλθ→%° </AnswerDescription>
</Answers>' as xml)

select N' ϱπΩ÷√νƞµΔϒᵨλθ→%°'
```

If these strings are being incorrectly stored in the database, it is likely that they are being implicitly cast to `VARCHAR` at some point during insertion (e.g. `INSERT`). It's also possible that they are being stored correctly and are cast to `VARCHAR` on retrieval (e.g. `SELECT`).

If you add some code to the question showing how you're inserting data and the datatypes of the target tables, it should be possible to provide more detailed assistance.

Comment: thanks Ed for pointing me at the right direction while inserting we were casting the XMl as varchar now we changed it to text and it worked fine. So what is the difference between the two ?

Comment: @Nikshep - don't use `text` - it's a deprecated type in SQL 2008 - use `NVARCHAR(MAX)` or SQL Server's built-in `XML` type.

Answer (score 1):

I believe its problem with incorectly set character set,
change charecter set to UTF8.
I just tested it on my MySQL database, i changed character set to utf8-bin using

```
ALTER TABLE  `tab1` CHANGE  `test`  `test` VARCHAR( 255 ) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL
```

worked without any problem

Comment: Question relates to MS SQL Server 2008 - this syntax is not supported